# What happens when a function that is being executed from a Qt Slot is called a second time when the signal is triggered again?

Tags: c++, qt

So here is my situation.

I'm writing a TCP server. This server will get requests from multiple clients.

I have a class that receives information (Based on a QTCPSocket called `MySocket`) and buffers it until all information has a arrived. To be clear, the client side sends its information as soon as it detects that it has sucesfully established a connection with my server class. Client and Server are separate programs running on different computers (actually even different OSs).

When `MySocket` has received all the data, it sends a qt signal to the Server Control Class. This is received in a slot that does many things depending on its only parameter. When the parameter tells it that the data has been received, it calls the function `ProcessInformation`. This function needs to do some stuff so it's not instantaneous.

If I get a new connection request on the server, this is saved in another instance of `MySocket` which will, again, emit its signal when all data has been received.

Here is where I'm not sure what will happen. I believe that the Qt Signal-Slot system will ensure that this works. If I'm not mistaken, since the slot function has not completed its run, the second signal will be queued and I'll get the desired behaviour: `ProcessInformation` will be called a second time, after it has finished its first run. However, I'm not sure, so I'm asking: How will the program behave in this scenario? So I can program accordingly.

Since these are two different programs running in different computers, and given the fact that I would require to test two clients sending its data simultaneously to see its effect, I'm not sure how to test this situation out.

Comment: I think that Qt will return to the event loop and call the slot again _after_ it has finished executing the functions from the previous call of the same slot.

Comment: Same thing that I think. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! That is actually a very interesting question. I hope someone writes a more detailed answer.

Comment: FYI: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example speaks a lot on Stackoverflow, and you are likely to attract more answers with that

Comment: @ WhiZTiM, I know you are right. But reproducing exactly this scenario without a whole bunch of code is very difficult. I did do a placeholder like example and placed it as an answer, I think it is the exact same thing

Answer (score 4):

> since the slot function has not completed its run, the second signal will be queued

***Categorically not.*** Qt never ever does that as a matter of course. Signals and slots are allowed to reenter.

The behavior depends on the *effective connection type*:

1. `Qt::DirectConnection` - the connection acts like immediately calling via a function pointer. **By the time the signal returns, the slot(s) have finished executing.** Effectively, it's as if `signal()`'s implementation simply had all the slot calls in it:

   ```
   signal(params) { slot(params); ... }
   ```
2. `Qt::QueuedConnection` - the connection acts like calling via a function pointer from within `exec()`:

   ```
   signal(params) { exec.add(slot, params); ... }
   ```

   Then `exec` (`QEventLoop::exec` or `QCoreApplication::exec`) does this:

   ```
   exec() { dispatchEvents(); while (!calls.empty()) calls.take_first().invoke(); }
   ```

Qt also supports an automatic connection, which is the default, where the effective type is determined at runtime within the signal:

```
signal(params) {
   for (conn: connections)
      sameThread = conn.receiver.thread() == currentThread();
      if (conn.isDirect || (conn.isAutomatic && sameThread))
         conn.slot(params)
      else if (conn.isQueued || (conn.isAutomatic && !sameThread))
         exec.add(conn.slot, params);
}
```

Thus, if you use the default automatic connection type, and the caller and receiver are in the same thread, then invoking the signal is the same as calling the slot directly in the receiver object. If the caller and receiver are in different threads, then invoking the signal will always queue the call to be executed when the control returns to the event loop.

Note that in Qt, in almost all cases, `exec()` is on the call stack whenever your code runs (any code of yours really). E.g. a call stack may look like this:

```
MyClass::onButtonClick()    // your slot connected to a button's clicked signal
QAbstractButton::clicked()  // signal - just a C++ method (!)
QPushButton::event()        // the event handler that got the mouse event
QCoreApplication::notify()
... (platform code etc)
QAbstractEventDispatcher::processEvents()
QCoreApplication::exec()
main()
__thread_start() 

       // C runtime code
```

Comment: Thank you for that!! Then there won't be a risk of loosing information.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So this is not the EXACT same situation that I was talking about. But it's (I think) close enough. Here is the code of a simple Tester widget with only one button to test out my problem.

The Header:

```
#ifndef TESTER_H
#define TESTER_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QFile>

namespace Ui {
class Tester;
}

class Tester : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Tester(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Tester();

public slots:
    void doStuff();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Tester *ui;
    QTimer timer;
    int ntimes;
    void aFunction();
};

#endif // TESTER_H
```

The CPP:

```
#include "tester.h"
#include "ui_tester.h"

Tester::Tester(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Tester)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ntimes = 50;
    connect(&timer,&QTimer::timeout,this,&Tester::doStuff);
}

void Tester::doStuff(){
    qWarning() << "DO STUFF";
    ntimes--;
    if (ntimes == 0) timer.stop();
    else aFunction();
}

void Tester::aFunction(){

    QFile file("output.txt");
    file.open(QFile::Append);
    QTextStream writer(&file);

    QElapsedTimer measure;
    measure.start();
    qWarning() << "AFUNCTION";
    writer << "CALL: " << ntimes << "\n";
    for (qint32 i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
        writer << "NUM" << i << "\n";
    }
    file.close();
    qWarning() << "LASTED" << measure.elapsed();

}

Tester::~Tester()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Tester::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //aFunction();
    timer.start(50);
}
```

My processing fucntion was replaced with simply `aFunction` which writes a bunch of numbers to a text file. I used the elapsed timer to measure how much time it takes for the function to completes and in average is about 220 ms.

So a timer signaling every 50 ms was used in place of My "all data has arrived" signal. If I'm correct, this should reproduce my problem. A signal will be sent to a slot that has a function when that function has not finished executing.

I tested it out and, as we suspected all numbers are written correctly for each call (which I checked using grep on the output file). Indicating that if a signal arrives on a slot that has not finished, the call to that slot is queued and the slot is called, as soon as the previous call ends.

I'd still appreciate any other confirmation.